# REACT useEffect() ignores localStorage and calls new API request anyway

Tags: reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I am making a catalogue-search app and I use a Context (API) to make API calls and store results.

PROBLEM #1: in the initial mount `useEffect` I check if localStorage has previous results and want to use them to fill the state. I have data in localStorage but the `useEffect` ignores it and calls `getSearchResults()` anyway. Why is that?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const searchResultsFromLS = getSearchFromLS();

    if (searchResultsFromLS) {
      setSearchResults(searchResultsFromLS); // doesn't work. Goes on to call getSearchResults() anyway.
    }

    getSearchResults();
  }, []);

const getSearchResults = async () => {
    if (searchText === "") {
      return;
    }
    const beers = await fetchBeers(
      searchText,
      searchType,
      pageNum,
      productsPerPage
    );

    setSearchResults(beers);
    setSearchInLS(beers);
  };
```

PROBLEM #2: The second `useEffect` fires whenever user refreshes the page because the `searchText` is set to empty string. So `useEffect` calls `getSearchResults()`. I want to persist the earlier search in case of page refresh so I tried to guard against the API call by adding the `if` at the top of `getSearchResults()` - so if the user just refreshes, an empty `searchText` shouldn't be able to trigger a new API call. But the API call is still made with an empty string! What's going on?? Many thanks, smart people.

```
// liten to state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    getSearchResults();
  }, [searchText, searchType, pageNum, productsPerPage]);

 const getSearchResults = async () => {
    if (searchText === "") {
      return;
    }
    const beers = await fetchBeers(
      searchText,
      searchType,
      pageNum,
      productsPerPage
    );

    setSearchResults(beers);
    setSearchInLS(beers);
  };
```

Comment: Please add defination of getSearchFromLS.

Comment: but your useEffect will allways call getSearchResults() what is surprising here?

Comment: you are not returning anything from if (searchResultsFromLS) { ...

Comment: @ZEE I'm returning the previous searchResults from LS: 
`export const getSearchFromLS = () => {
  const searchResultsInLS = localStorage.getItem("searchResults");
  const searchResults = searchResultsInLS ? JSON.parse(searchResultsInLS) : [];
  return searchResults;
};`

Comment: in this case you need to return the function itself getSearchResults in the if condition